# Lunar and solar tides

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solar-system, tidal-effect

I just read the following statement in a book:

> *If the diameter of the earth increased by 20%, both lunar and solar tides would be weakened with lunar tides weakening more than solar tides.*

What does this mean? I basically don't know about solar tides and how lunar and solar tides are related.

Comment: Does the book say why they would be weakened?

Comment: if the diameter of earth increases by 20%....

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which book?

Answer (score 1):

The tides happen because the side of the Earth facing the Moon is nearer to the Moon that the other side of the Earth, so the gravitational field of the Moon is stronger on one side of the Earth than the other. The tidal force is derived in the Wikipedia article on [tidal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force): I'll just quote the result:

$$ F \approx \frac{G M_{Earth} M_{Moon} }{r^3} d$$

where $r$ is the distance from the centre of the Earth to the centre of the Moon, and $d$ is the diameter of the Earth. $F$ is the force stretching the Earth i.e. the difference between the forces on the near and far sides. The approximation assumes that the diameter of the Earth, $d$, is much less than the Earth Moon distance.

So firstly increasing the diameter of the Earth will increase the tidal force not decrease it, and secondly the tidal force is approximately proportional to the Earth's diameter, so an increase of 20% will increase the solar and luner tides by the same ratio of 20%.